# Disable screen dimming in Ubuntu Mate 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: 18.04, power-management, screen, brightness, ubuntu-mate

I want to disable dimming of the screen occurring after every about 60 seconds of being idle. I tried going to *Menu* → *Power Management*, then unchecked *Dim display when idle* checkboxes in both *On AC Power* and *On Battery Power* tabs. I also tried the following commands but the screen still keeps on dimming after about a minute:

```
xset -dpms
```

and

```
xset s off
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that after also unchecking the *Reduce backlight brightness* checkbox in the *On Battery Power* tab of *Power Management Preferences*, the screen no longer dims:

[image: Power Management Preferences]